# Injecting bean references based on some Parameter

Tags: spring, dynamic, dependency-injection, javabeans

I want to inject a bean reference based on a parameter.
Basically i am developing a module which will be used in multiple application. Say functionality 'X' (which will be implemented in a method) will differ with respect to application.
I have a base abstract class and its sub classes will have implementations based on application.

I want to induce the bean reference based on the application which is using the module.
Its a Factory Pattern.
I want to know what is the best way to implement the same (In a Spring way).

Below is the Sample code which i want to implement

```
Class SuperAbstClass{
  public SomeType doSomething();

}
Class SomeClass extends SuperAbstClass{
  public Sometype doSomething(){ // do something }
}

class SomeOtherClass extends SuperAbstClass{
  public SomeType doSomething(){
            // Do Some other thing.
   }
}
```

Above code will be a maven module and this module can be used in multiple applications (Closely linked). app_name is the param. based on this param, i want to inject respective implementations.

Comment: I think your question would be better with a sample of code. Can you do it ?

Comment: Not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for, but it sounds like maybe you want [Spring Profiles](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html)

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave - Profiles are something based on environment.I shall post you an example

Comment: If you're trying to post code here, the best idea would be to edit your question, to add the additional information there.